# How to get image to scroll behind navbar

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a web page with a navbar fixed at the top and the rest of the page should scroll up beneath the navbar. Most of the elements do scroll behind it. There are three images side by side. The two outside images (img 1 & img 3) scroll underneath the navbar as they should, but the central image (img 2) does not. It scrolls above the navbar.  I think it has something to do with it being position absolute, but how can I get this one image to behave like everything else on the page? If I remove the position absolute the image no longer appears in line with the others. If I add a z-index of 1 it still goes over the navbar, despite the navbar having a z-index of 300. If I give the image a z-index of -1 it disappears altogether. I have tried adding different z-index values to different elements but cannot find a combination that works.

Here is my relevant css:

```
.navigate{
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

    .toggle,
    [id^=drop] {
        display: none;
    }


    nav { 
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 300;
    }

    nav:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 70px; 
    }

    .spread1{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        background-color: #0555bd;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .imgHolder{
        width:60%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .img1{
        display: block;
        width: 27%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0 ;
        float: left;
        }
    .img2{
        position: absolute;
        width: 25%;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .img3{
        width: 27%;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0 ;
        float: right;
        }
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="navigate">      
   <nav>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="AMD logo"></div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="spread1">
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img class="img1" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="img1" />
    <img class="img2" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="img 2" />
    <img class="img3" src="images/image3" alt="img 3" />

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must go up the tree and find the level where the ancestor of `<nav>` is a sibling of `img2`'s ancestor. Then apply a higher `z-index` value to `<nav>`s ancestor which happens to be `div.navigate` which has `z-index:300` now.  See demo below.

```
.navigate{
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    /* FIX */
    z-index:300;
}
```

Also, I had to add 2 rulesets to `.spread1` because the OP was not scrolling. These 2 changes are not a requirement of solution, it's just here to demonstrate that the image scrolls under `<nav>`

```
   .spread1{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        background-color: #0555bd;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* Added to test scroll */
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:100vh;
    }
```

### Demo

```css
.navigate{
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    /* FIX */
    z-index:300;
}

    .toggle,
    [id^=drop] {
        display: none;
    }


    nav { 
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 300;
    }

    nav:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 70px; 
    }

    .spread1{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        background-color: #0555bd;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* Added to test scroll */
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .imgHolder{
        width:60%;
        margin: auto;

    }
    .img1{
        display: block;
        width: 27%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0 ;
        float: left;
        }
    .img2{
        position: absolute;
        width: 25%;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .img3{
        width: 27%;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0 ;
        float: right;
        }
```

```html
<div class="navigate">      
   <nav>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="AMD logo"></div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="spread1">
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img class="img1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1'" alt="img1" />
    <img class="img2" src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0ff/000?text=2' alt="img 2" />
    <img class="img3" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/83d800/000?text=3" alt="img 3" />

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `navigate` class and `container` class are on the same "level" you should apply your z-indexing there. Some items will appear above your menu is because of the `position: absolute`and applying your `z-index` on the `navigate` class will fix it.

```
.navigate{
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used flexbox for CSS? It makes it a lot easier to position and align elements on a page.

When I'm troubleshooting alignment issues, my first step is usually to delete unnecessary elements. You seem to have a ton of divs. I realize you may not have posted all of the code to show why these nested divs might be relevant to your project, but for my answer, I took them out or updated them to add HTML5 elements, such as `header`.

Flexbox provides a way to dynamically layout elements in a container. For an in depth description/tutorial, check this out [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You'd want to set the imgHolder element to `display: flex`, and the children images to `flex: 1`. This would position them closer to how you want them, without mixing absolute positioning and floats. Floats are really only supposed to be used with text/img position (although we often don't follow that).

**HTML**

```
  <div class="imgHolder">

    <img class="img1" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="img1" />
    <img class="img2" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="img 2" />
    <img class="img3" src="images/image3" alt="img 3" />

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header { 
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 110px;
}

.toggle, [id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 110px; /* height of header */
}

.imgHolder{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: #0555bd;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.imgHolder img {
  flex: 1;
}
```

After that, you'd want to tweak the images to align where you want them. There are some css attributes like `justify-content` that helps you place them centered, to the right, to the left, etc.

Finally, I made a working bin [here](http://jsbin.com/gatacis/edit?html,css,output) for you to reference.